# SQLITE Exception Handling: Why must I reset the statement twice after foreign key violation?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I'm using SQLITE 3.8.7 and am trying to create a custom exception handling class whenever a statement fails a constraint such as a foreign key constraint violation or if a sqlite3_step statement returns SQLITE_MISUSE.

In my destructor, I perform 1) a rollback; 2) cleanup; 3) log the exception.

```
~SQLException()
{
    try
    {
        _db->Execute("ROLLBACK");
        try
        {
           _db->ResetStatement();
        }
        catch (sql_exception anotherException)
        {
           _db->ResetStatement();
        }

        LOG_ERROR("sql_exception: %d %s\n", _e.code, _e.message.c_str());
    }
    catch (sql_execption ex)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("sql_exception: %d %s\n", ex.code, ex.message.c_str());
    }
```

Execute() is just a wrapper around sqlite3_exec while ResetStatement() is a wrapper around sqlite3_reset().

```
void DatabaseConnection::Execute(const char* text)
{
   ASSERT(_handle);

   auto const result = sqlite3_exec(_handle.get(), text, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

   if (SQLITE_OK != result)
   {
      throw sql_exception(result, sqlite3_errmsg(_handle.get()));
   }
}

void DatabaseConnection::ResetStatement()
{
   auto const result = sqlite3_reset(_stmt.get());

   if (SQLITE_OK != result)
   {
      throw sql_exception(result, sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3_db_handle(_stmt.get())));
   }
}
```

I wrote a unit test that triggered a foreign key constraint violation (which triggers this cleanup code), and then try and perform additional inserts like nothing happened.  The rollback works fine but the first reset throws the same foreign key constrain violation exception.  It is only when I call ResetStatement() a second time do things get cleaned up and I'm able to continue with additional inserts, etc.

**Why does the reset statement need to be called twice?**

Thanks.

UPDATE: Here's a simple example that causes both ResetStatements() to be hit...

```
Table 1: Teams
TeamID INTEGER NOT NULL,
Name TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(TeamID)

Table 2: Players
PlayerID INTEGER NOT NULL,
Name TEXT NOT NULL,
TeamID INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(PlayerID),
FOREIGN KEY(TeamID) REFERENCES Teams(TeamID)

try
{
    INSERT INTO Players VALUES(1, "Joe Montana", 1) -->causes expected Foreign Key constraint violation and you cannot proceed with another insert until ResetStatement() is called twice.
}
catch (...)
{
    SQLException();
}
```

So far this seems to only occur with Foreign Key Constraint violations.  Other exceptions I've thrown at it seem to be properly reset after only one call.

This is raw database code.  The commented line retains the Foreign Key Constraint violation on the first pass (rc == 19), but is on the second pass (rc ==0).

```
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_reset(sqlite3_stmt *pStmt){
  int rc;
  if( pStmt==0 ){
    rc = SQLITE_OK;
  }else{
    Vdbe *v = (Vdbe*)pStmt;
    sqlite3_mutex_enter(v->db->mutex);
    rc = sqlite3VdbeReset(v); //first pass rc = 19, second pass rc = 0
    sqlite3VdbeRewind(v);
    assert( (rc & (v->db->errMask))==rc );
    rc = sqlite3ApiExit(v->db, rc);
    sqlite3_mutex_leave(v->db->mutex);
  }
  return rc;
}
```

The same behavior exists in the latest version of SQLite, 3.8.11.1.

Comment: This cannot be answered without seeing the complete program. But why does the destructor of the exception object do a rollback? Shouldn't this be done in the destructor of the transaction?

Comment: Ease of implementation but you're probably right that it should be done at the transaction level. There is a DatabaseManager module that provides an interface to the rest of the system, hiding the SQL statements, etc.  Each method has a try/catch where this exception is used so as soon as the scope of the catch is gone, the destructor is called.  Logging is not available at the transaction level although that could be remedied.  I'll see if I can reproduce the issue with a simple example as I cannot share the program.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described behavior of `sqlite3_reset` is nowadays [documented](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html):

> If the most recent call to sqlite3_step(S) for the prepared statement
> S returned SQLITE_ROW or SQLITE_DONE, or if sqlite3_step(S) has never
> before been called on S, then sqlite3_reset(S) returns SQLITE_OK.
>
> If the most recent call to sqlite3_step(S) for the prepared statement
> S indicated an error, then sqlite3_reset(S) returns an appropriate
> error code.

This is probably a legacy of the initial [goofy interface](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) of the `sqlite3_step`, which returned only generic SQLITE_ERROR code, and the one needed to call `sqlite3_reset` or `sqlite3_finalize` in order to find the specific error code, which better described the error. The interface has been updated since then to allow `sqlite3_step` to return the specific error codes directly, but `sqlite3_reset` still behaves the old way.